# Intellij - Erro Java - Gradle sync failed: Cannot convert relative path ~/GRADLE_HOME/daemon/6.8 to an absolute file

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

O problema está aparecendo sempre que tento rodar o programa, e as *packages* do programa não aparecem também. Abri o mesmo projeto pelo *VSCode* e funcionou normalmente por lá, só não está funcionando pelo *IntelliJ*.

Answer (score -1):

O Intellij não está conseguindo transformar o diretório setado com `~` do caminho do gradle para um diretório do disco.

No MAC:
`Intellij` --> `Preferences`

No Windows/Linux:
`File` --> `Settings`

Depois, independente do sistema operacional:

`Build, Execution, Deployment` --> `Build Tools` --> `Gradle`

Em *Gradle User Home*, veja se tem um `~` lá. Se tiver (esse é o erro mais comum), troque por um path/caminho sem o ~. Substitua por exemplo por:
`/home/nomeusuario/.gradle` se este for o caminho do gradle.

Answer (score -3):

opa, boa noite amigo, tudo bem?
Eu já tinha feito isso antes, mas não tive sucesso nem mesmo com essa mudança.